# web application to workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation

I am developing an web application using window workflow foundation. I will send an email to others by using this application. In that for every recipient an workflow instance will be created.

The recipient can login my web application using the link provided in that email.
When the login in my application I should change the workflow state for that recipient.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to implement persistence for your workflow. Because there may be lot of time between sending email and user actually logging in again.

After sending email the workflow will be idle and will be persisted by runtime services.
When user logs in you need to pullout right workflow from persistence store (you may store id against their login or some other mechanism that suites you to associate user with workflow instance). Then call the workflow events and change its state as you wish!

[Here](http://whiteknighttechnology.com/cs/blogs/bayer_white/archive/2007/04/17/1284.aspx) is link to Bayer White's post about workflow persistence (with sample), 
this one is at [devx.com](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/32247)

Comment: I persisted my workflow. I have local service class which is used for workflow service class. When user login i get workflow instanceid from database at that time local service object is null. Then How can I call the workflow events?